# Select only the persons that have both values

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
ClientID | PhoneType
    1    |  4
    1    |  4
    1    |  5
    2    |  4
    3    |  5
```

I'm trying to wright a query to only show the client who have both phone types.
So output should only show client ID 1

As you notice, client 1 has two type '4' PhoneTypes, so I'm trying not to use a GroupBy/HavingCount of method to narrow the result down. Which were the only examples I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like...

```
SELECT x.ClientID
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, PhoneType FROM [Table A]
) AS x
GROUP BY x.ClientID
HAVING COUNT(x.PhoneType) = 2
```

DISTINCT is used to remove duplicates from the COUNT in case the client has 2 or more phones of the same type.

Comment: I think you still need a `GROUP BY x.ClientID` don't you?

Comment: @Jeff - Cheers. Now added. Just threw it together from memory.

Comment: it would be good to explain why the `distinct` makes this the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had tried your method and it was throwing an error at me to group. I added it last night and it worked. I guess I HAVE to use it, ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a SQL Server currently, but it seems like you should be able to use the following, which is a little simpler than Gavin's answer:

```
SELECT ClientID
FROM [Table A]
GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PhoneType) = 2
```

Not entirely sure that count distinct works in `HAVING`, but I don't see why it wouldn't...